# Question about this sentence 'Der Katechismus der römisch-katholischen Kirche'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Der Katechismus der römisch-katholischen Kirche

Why is 'der' used and not 'von'?

> Der Katechismus der römisch-katholischen Kirche grenzt die lässliche Sünde (lateinisch peccatum veniale) als minderschweres, geringfügiges Vergehen von der Todsünde ab.

This is the full sentence, so in this case 'Der Katechismus' is the Nominative is that right?

Comment: That's not a complete sentence at all.

Comment: Because it's in the *Genitiv* case. You don't need a `von` there.

Comment: A complete sentence isn't needed here.

Comment: ''Der Katechismus der römisch-katholischen Kirche grenzt die lässliche Sünde (lateinisch peccatum veniale) als minderschweres, geringfügiges Vergehen von der Todsünde ab.'' This is the full sentence, so in this case 'Der Katechismus' is the Nominative is that right?

Comment: @Yozansen Add additional information to your question, rather stating in comments please.

Comment: This is the title of a book, by the way:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechism_of_the_Catholic_Church

Comment: @David Vogt

'This is the full sentence, so in this case 'Der Katechismus' is the Nominative is that right? '

I meant my follow up question stated here jackass. He could have replied a simple 'yes it is' or 'no it isn't it is THIS instead'  On top of his comment about me adding information to my question. Unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Der Katechismus **der römisch-katholischen Kirche** …

This is a genitive attribute. German uses the genitive case much more often than e.g. English uses its possessive case and those genitive attributes are the most common use.